# How to correctly get the computer to guess a user's number in 7 questions

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++ with the book "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++," and I'm doing an exercise where the computer is supposed to guess a user's number from 1 to 100 in 7 questions. My code almost works, but the computer cannot guess the upper bound (100). How can I fix this? Here's my code.

```
#include "..\std_lib_facilities_revised.h"

int main()
{
    int low = 1;
    int high = 100;
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    char response = ' ';
    cout << "Think of a number between 1 and 100.\n";
    while (low < mid) {
        cout << "low: " << low << '\n';
        cout << "high: " << high << '\n';
        cout << "mid: " << mid << '\n';
        cout << "Is your number less than " << mid << "? (y for yes, anything else for no)\n";
        cin >> response;
        if (response == 'y') {
            high = mid;
            mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        }
        else {
            low = mid;
            mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        }
    }
    cout << "Your number is: " << low << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an off-by-one error. Have you debugged it for 100 step by step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your candidate interval contains an even number of entries, you choose the midpoint that is closer to the lower end. Specifically, if you have two numbers `a` and `b`, the midpoint will be `a`. Thus, asking if the number is smaller than the midpoint (`a`) does not give you any information. You already know that this is not the case.

Instead, you can choose the midpoint to be closer to the upper end:

```
mid = low + (high - low + 1) / 2;
```

A second thing you should change is the interval adaptation for the `y` case. The number is *smaller than mid*. Hence, the new upper bound should be `mid - 1`.

Comment: Seems slightly more intuitive to write `mid = high - (high - low) / 2;`

Comment: Thank you! It works for 100 now. Adapting the `y` case to `mid - 1` makes sense, but I don't know if I fully understand why you add the `+ 1` in the mid assignment. Is it because you considered the case where low is 99 and high is 100, and because of integer division an extra 1 was needed to bump mid up to 100, or is it something else?

Comment: This `+1` is simply rounding up. William's variant achieves the same thing. Maybe, it is more intuitive to you.